# Object reference not set to an instance of an object while initializing items for a Soap request as per the WSDL

Tags: c#, .net, wsdl

I have a WSDL which contains `OrderInformation_type` class consisting of three private attributes which are classes themselves: `Header_type`, `PromotionInformation_type` and an array of `ItemInformation_type[]` respectively. I have initialized an object of `OrderInformation_type` as 'order'. Further, I have initialized `order.Header_type` header and `order.PromotionInformation_type` objects which are initialized successfully and their attributes can be set easily. But when I try to initialize the `order.ItemInformation_type[]` object I get an error at run time stating, object reference not set to an instance of an `object.Considering`, that the `OrderInformation_type` has `ItemInformation_type` attribute as an array thus I initialize it in the following way:

```
WindowsFormsApplication1.ServiceReference1.OrderInformation_type orderinfo = new ServiceReference1.OrderInformation_type();
            orderinfo.Header = new ServiceReference1.Header_type();
            orderinfo.Header.AccountNumber = 496570;
            orderinfo.Header.DistributorIdentifier = ServiceReference1.Header_typeDistributorIdentifier.MBA;

            orderinfo.PromotionInformation = new ServiceReference1.PromotionInformation_type();
            **orderinfo.ItemInformation[0] = new ServiceReference1.ItemInformation_type();**
            orderinfo.ItemInformation[0].ItemID = "95847";
            orderinfo.ItemInformation[0].ItemIDType = ServiceReference1.ItemInformation_typeItemIDType.D;
            orderinfo.ItemInformation[0].Quantity = 1;
```

The Bold one is the line where it get the error.

Comment: Unless you have a constructor, `new ServiceReference1.OrderInformation_type()` does not automatically create a ItemInformation array (or list).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The rest two are being initialized, the header and promotioninformation but the iteminformation isn’t. The classes are generated from wsdl automatically. How can jt miss the constructor? I think there is issue with the attribute being an array. Since the element can exist multiple times as shown in the wsdl

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

orderinfo.ItemInformation is an array.  You are trying to assign to [0] on something that has not been created yet.  Adding

> orderinfo.ItemInformation = new new
>   ServiceReference1.PromotionInformation_type[];

should do it...

Comment: ServiceReference1.ItemInformation = new ServiceRefernce1.ItemInformation[];

Comment: Yes it does give the same not set to an instance of an object error

Comment: That line should be prior to the line that’s throwing the exception.  Also ensure that the new exception is on the same line.  That exception makes no sense on that line if you have initialized the array.

Comment: No, that line should have a number in it : `new ServiceRefernce1.ItemInformation[10];`